# Send array checkbox value in PHP form Yes/No

Tags: php, forms, http-post

Iam sending a php checkbox value to another php page in turn is saving this array of data to mysql db.

My php form is as follows:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='gt[]' id='gt[]' value='Yes' $checked>
```

Php page which is saving the form data is as follows:

```
$size = count($_POST['unitprice']);
$i = 0;

while ($i < $size) {
    if (isset($_POST['gt'][$i]) && $_POST['gt'][$i] == 'Yes') {
        $gt = "Yes";
    } else {
        $gt = "No";
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Followed by an update query

The whole php form is as follows:

```
        <?php
        //mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        //mysql_select_db("test") or die("Unable to select database");
         include('config.php');

        $tender_id=$_GET['tender_id'];

        echo "<form name='cart' method='post' class='single' action='generate_quot_cust_edititems_save_complete.php?tender_id=$tender_id' >\n";

        echo "<input type='hidden' name='sum_input' id='sum_input' value=''>";

        $sql = "select id,slno,item_name,prod_description,slab_range,qty,qty_sup,item_units,item_units_sup,unitprice,currency,total,total_inr,add_percentage,add_value,addon_value,price_unit,currency_selected,grand_total,comm_amend_req,tech_amend_req,total1,margin_for,slab_checked,margin_total from quotation_items where tender_id='$tender_id' order by slno";

        //$sql = "select id,slno,item_name,prod_description,qty,item_units,unitprice,currency,total,total_inr,add_percentage,add_value,addon_value,price_unit,currency_selected,grand_total,comm_amend_req,tech_amend_req,total1 from quotation_items where tender_id='$tender_id'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

        $i = 0;

        echo '<div align="center"><table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">';
        echo '<tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">';
        //echo "<td width='3%'>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo '<td width=4%>SlNo</td>';
        echo '<td width=17%>Description</td>';
        echo '<td width=5%>Slab</td>';
        echo '<td width=4%>Qty</td>';
        echo '<td width=4%>Units</td>';
        echo '<td width=5%>Unit Price</td>';
        echo '<td width=4%>Curr</td>';
        echo '<td width=6%>Total</td>';
        echo '<td width=7%>Total INR</td>';
        echo '<td width=5%>Add (%)</td>';
        echo '<td width=5%>Add Value</td>';
        echo '<td width=7%>Total Value</td>';
        echo '<td width=5%>Currency</td>';
        echo '<td width=7%>Total</td>';
        echo '<td width=7%>Price/Unit</td>';
        echo '<td width=8%>Margin</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table></div>';
        $num=0;
        $slno1 = 0;
        //if($list5['tech_amend_req'] === '1') echo checked='checked'
        while ($list5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $slno1++;
        if ($list5['slab_checked'] == '') $checked = '';
        if ($list5['slab_checked'] == 'No') $checked = '';
        if ($list5['slab_checked'] == 'Yes') $checked = 'checked=checked';

        $currency_selected=$list5['currency_selected'];

        //echo $checked;
        //<a href='#' class='addNew'>&nbsp;+</a>
        echo '<div align="center" class="base">';
        echo '<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">';
            echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td width='4%'><input size='1' type='hidden' name='id[$i]' value='{$list5['id']}' readonly/><input size='1' type='text' name='sl[$i]' value='{$slno1}' readonly/></td>";
        echo "<td width='17%' id='addinput'><input type='text' size='22' id='item_name$i' name='item_name[$i]' placeholder='{$list5['prod_description']}' value='{$list5['prod_description']}' /></td>";
        echo "<td width='5%'><input size='4' class='slab_range' type='text' name='slab_range[]' id='slab_range[]' value='{$list5['slab_range']}' readonly/></td>";
        echo "<td width='4%'><input size='1' class='qty' type='text' name='qty[]' id='qty[]' value='{$list5['qty_sup']}' readonly/></td>";
         echo "<td width='4%'><input size='2' type='text' name='item_units[$i]' value='{$list5['item_units_sup']}' readonly/></td>";
            echo "<td width='5%'><input size='4' type='text' name='unitprice[$i]' value='{$list5['unitprice']}' readonly/></td>";
        echo "<td width='4%'><input size='2' type='text' name='currency[$i]' value='{$list5['currency']}' /></td>";
            echo "<td width='6%'><input size='5' type='text' name='total_old' value='{$list5['total']}' readonly/></td>";
        //echo "<td width='8%'><input size='4' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value='{$list5['total_inr']}'/></td>";
            $cur = $list5['currency'];
        $t= $list5['total'];
            $sql_cur_inr = "select * from currency1 where currency='INR'";
                        $result_cur_inr = mysql_query($sql_cur_inr) or die($sql_cur_inr."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
            $list_cur_inr = mysql_fetch_array($result_cur_inr);

          $sql_cur = "select * from currency1";
                    $result_cur = mysql_query($sql_cur) or die($sql_cur."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
           while ($row_cur = mysql_fetch_array($result_cur)) {
            $rate = $row_cur['rate'];
            $rate_inr = $list_cur_inr['rate'];
                    }
                echo "<td width='7%'><input size='7' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value='{$list5['total_inr']}'/></td>";
            //echo "<td width='8%'><input size='10' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value='{$total_inr}' /></td>";
         echo "<td width='5%' ><input class='' size='2' type='text' id='add_percentage[]' name='add_percentage[]' value='{$list5['add_percentage']}' onchange='calcTotals()'></td>";

            echo "<td width='5%'><input class='txt' type='text' size='3' id='addon_value[]' name='addon_value[]' value='{$list5['addon_value']}' onchange='calcTotals()' ></td>";

        echo "<td width='7%'><input class='total'  size='7' type='text' id='add_value[]' name='add_value[]' value='{$list5['add_value']}' ></td>";
        ?>
    <?php
        $currency_selected1=$list5['currency_selected'];

          $selectedValue = "$currency_selected1"; // assign that value to this variable
        //echo $selectedValue;
          echo "<td width='5%'>";
          $sql_currency = "SELECT * FROM currency1";
          $result_currency = mysql_query($sql_currency);
          echo "<select id='currency_change[]' name='currency_change[]'>";
        echo "<option value=''>select</option>"; 
          /*
           * selected value
           */
          $selectedValue = "$currency_selected1"; // assign that value to this variable
          while ($row_currency = mysql_fetch_array($result_currency)) {
              $selected = "";
             if($row_currency['currency'] == $selectedValue){
                 $selected = ' selected="selected" ';
             }
          //echo "<option ".$selected." disabled hidden value=''>select</option>"; 
              echo "<option ".$selected." value=" . $row_currency['currency'] . " data-price=" . $row_currency['rate'] . ">" . $row_currency['currency'] . "</option>";
          }
          echo "</select>";
          echo "</td>";
          ?>
    <?php $sql_cur = "select * from currency1 where currency='INR' LIMIT 1";
        $result_cur = mysql_query($sql_cur) or die($sql_cur."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        $list_cur = mysql_fetch_array($result_cur);

        ?>
    <input type="hidden" class="inrvalue" id="inrvalue" name="inrvalue" value="<?php echo $list_cur['rate']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" class="deptip" id="dept-input"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="priceip" id="price-input"/>
    <input type="hidden" class="cs" id="cs" name="cs" value="<?php echo $list5['currency_selected']; ?>">
    <td width="7%"><input size="7" type="text" data-value="<?php $list5['total1'] ?>" name='total1[]' id='total1[]' value="<?php echo $list5['total1'] ?>" readonly class="total1"/></td>
    <?php
        echo "<td width='7%'><input class='price_unit' size='7' type='text' id='price_unit[]' name='price_unit[]' value='{$list5['price_unit']}' 
            readonly></td>";
        echo "<td width='8%'><input type='checkbox' name='gt[]' id='gt[]' value='Yes'><input size='8' type='text' id='margin_for[]' name='margin_for[]' value='{$list5['margin_for']}' readonly></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo '';
            ++$i;
           }

           $sql = "select grand_total,margin_total, sum(total_inr) as totalinr_total from quotation_items where tender_id='$tender_id' LIMIT 1";

           $result_gt = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        $list_gt = mysql_fetch_array($result_gt);

           //echo '<table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">';
           echo '<tr>';
           echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
           echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
           echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
           echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
           echo '<td></td>';
           echo '<td></td>';
           echo '<td></td>';
           echo "<td><input type='text' style='font-weight: bold' name='total_inr1' id='total_inr1' size='8' value='{$list_gt['totalinr_total']}' readonly /></td>";
           echo "<td></td>";
           echo '<td></td>';
           echo "<td><input type='text' style='font-weight: bold' name='gTotal' id='grand_total' size='7' value='{$list_gt['grand_total']}' readonly /></td>";
           echo "<td></td>";
           echo '<td></td>';
           echo "<td></td>";
           echo "<td><input type='text' style='font-weight: bold'  id='margin_total' name='margin_total' size='8' value='{$list_gt['margin_total']}' readonly /></td>";
           echo '</tr>';
           echo '</table></div>';
        ?>
    <br>
    <?php
        $validity_chk=$list['validity_chk'];
        $incoterm_chk=$list['incoterm_chk'];
        $freight_chk=$list['freight_chk'];
        $cdcterms_chk=$list['cdcterms_chk'];
        $poto_chk=$list['poto_chk'];
        $paymentterms_chk=$list['paymentterms_chk'];
        $delivery_chk=$list['delivery_chk'];
        ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="validity_chk" id="validity_chk" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="incoterm_chk" id="incoterm_chk" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="freight_chk" id="incoterm_chk" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cdcterms_chk" id="cdcterms_chk" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="poto_chk" id="poto_chk" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentterms_chk" id="paymentterms_chk" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_chk" id="delivery_chk" value="0" />
    <?php include('note.php');?><br>
    <?php include('terms.php');?>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" height="60">Authorized Signature</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <?php
                    $t5 = $list['po_to'];

                    if ($t5 == "Umac Bangalore") {
                        echo 'Sandhya';
                    } else if ($t5 == "Umac Singapore") {
                       echo 'Arijith Das';
                    } 
                    else {
                        echo "";
                    }?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <?php
        echo "<table border='0' width='13%'><td><input type='submit' value='--Save Data--' /></td>";
        echo '';
        echo '';
        echo '';
        ?>
```

And following is the complete php part which is saving the form data:

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $tender_id=$_GET['tender_id'];
    $size = count($_POST['unitprice']);
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, 1) . '</pre>'; 

       $i = 0;
       while ($i < $size) {
        $item_name= $_POST['item_name'][$i];
        $currency= $_POST['currency'][$i];
        //$add_percentage_v= $_POST['add_percentage_v'.$i];
        $add_percentage= $_POST['add_percentage'][$i];
        $add_value= $_POST['add_value'][$i];
        $addon_value= $_POST['addon_value'][$i];
        $price_unit= $_POST['price_unit'][$i];
        $total_inr= $_POST['total_inr'][$i];
        $margin= $_POST['margin_for'][$i];
        //$gt=$_POST['gt'][$i];
    //$gt = $_POST['gt'][$i];
    //if ($gt != 'Yes') {
    //    $gt = 'No';
    //} 

    if (isset($_POST['gt'][$i]) && $_POST['gt'][$i] == 'Yes') {
       $gt = "Yes";
    } else {
       $gt = "No";
    }
        $total1=$_POST['total1'][$i];
        $currency_selected=$_POST['currency_change'][$i];

        $sum_input= $_POST['gTotal'];

        $margin_total= $_POST['margin_total'];
        $totalinr_total= $_POST['total_inr1'];

        $id = $_POST['id'][$i];

    $query = "UPDATE quotation_items SET prod_description = '$item_name',currency = '$currency',add_percentage = '$add_percentage',addon_value = '$addon_value',add_value = '$add_value',grand_total = '$sum_input', price_unit='$price_unit', currency_selected='$currency_selected',  total1='$total1', total_inr='$total_inr', margin_for='$margin', slab_checked='$gt', margin_total='$margin_total', totalinr_total='$totalinr_total' WHERE id = '$id' and tender_id='$tender_id' ";
        mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");


        echo "$item_name<br />$add_value<br />$margin<br /><em>Quot Updated!</em><br /><br />";
        ++$i;
       }
       ?>
```

Comment: Please provide more of your code. Eg $i is not defined in what you have provided.

Comment: Maybe because you only have first checkbox "checked" or even only have one checked checkbox available as shown in your code

Comment: @sinaza. Now i removed "checked" part, still in the db the first row is checked (Yes). Really confused on this..

Comment: @SanjuMenon, I'v lightly refactored your code and added $i++ to prevent infinit loop.

Comment: I tried to simulate your code but I'm getting the correct result. Put the whole HTML form code as well

Comment: I have modified the question and put the whole php form page. Its bit long..

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked checkbox values are not presented in $_POST array, so you should replace 'Yes' checkbox value with actual value.

Simple dirty non-mvc example (you may test it in index.php file of your webroot to clarify things):

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'coding'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'database'),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'html/css'),
);
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $row['name'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" value="1">
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $l = count($_POST['id']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
        $id = intval($_POST['id'][$i]);
        $checked = isset($_POST['hobby'][$id]) ? 'checked' : 'not checked';
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'][$i]) . " was $checked<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Or see [runnable](http://code.runnable.com/VlBDJkSEK18hgPYV/handle-multimple-checkboxes-for-php)

Comment: i have edited the question with the php actual code which is saving the form data. Can u pls check and tell me where exactly iam doing wrong..

Comment: Code is so messy :) Maybe, somebody will refactor it lately. You should understand that your `$_POST['gt']` contains values of checked checkboxes.

Comment: @SanjuMenon, I'v replaced the example, hope this helps to get the basic idea.

Comment: In the php page i gave $gt = isset($_POST['gt'][$i]) ? $_POST['gt'][$i] : "No";
which is working fine now. Really thank you for ur guidance. Really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the following code, you will see that, $result will return the array of selected checkbox values.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $result = $_POST['gt'];
    print_r($result);
}
?>
```

Comment: Iam getting an error when i execute this part of code : Notice: Array to string conversion in "

Comment: replace echo with print_r($result); cause $result is an array. Check the edited code @SanjuMenon

Comment: This is the result which am getting "Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes ) Array ( [0] => Yes )" which is wrong

Comment: Are you putting it in a loop?